# Does Swagger UI have permalinks for paths?

Tags: swagger-ui

Is it possible to link to a specific path displayed in Swagger UI, such as to `/work/2.1` on the image below?

[image: This is my swagger ui relative path]

I want to link to individual paths from an external web page.

Comment: Do you mean something like operation permalinks? As in, a link that automatically navigates to / expands a specific operation in Swagger UI?

Comment: Yes. Like perma links that would literally take me to a particular path in swagger ui.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, Swagger UI has [permalinks](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/deep-linking.md) for operations and tags. To get a permalink, expand an operation or tag and copy the URL in the address bar. Permalinks look like this:

```
index.html#/tagName
index.html#/tagName/operationId
```

When someone opens such a permalink in a browser, the corresponding tag or operation is automatically expanded and also scrolled to the top if needed. Example:
https://petstore.swagger.io/#/store/getInventory

In Swagger UI 2.2 permalinks are enabled by default.

If you use UI 3.x, you need version 3.0.19 or later, and you need to add `deepLinking: true` to the Swagger UI init code in your `index.html`:

```js
const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
  url: "http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json",
  deepLinking: true,  // <------
```

Comment: Thank you Helen! I am sorry about confusing the question but the answer was exactly what I was looking for. I tried it and was able to work with it. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

Added Deep Link support to SwaggerUI:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    ...
    c.EnableDeepLinking();
});
```

Comment: Code alone makes for a pretty low quality answer. Could you explain us what your code snippet does?