# How to link to another endpoint in Swagger

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I'm writing a Swagger specification for an future public API that requires a very detailed and clean documentation. **Is there a way to reference/link/point to another endpoint at some other location in the *swagger.yml* file?**

For example, here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
paths:
  /my/endpoint:
    post:
      tags:
        - Some tag
      summary: Do things
      description: >
        This endpoint does things.
        See /my/otherEndpoint for stuff  # Here I would like to have some kind of hyperlink
      operationId: doThings
      consumes:
        - application/json
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        ...
      responses:
        ...
  /my/otherEndpoint:  # This is the endpoint to be referenced to
    get:
      ...
```

I have found that `$ref` does not help because it simply replaces itself with the contents of the reference.

Can Swagger do such a thing?

Comment: Which tool do you use to render the documentation - Swagger UI or something else?

Comment: Right now I'm working with https://editor.swagger.io/ but the API will use Swagger UI

Comment: check out YAML-native Anchors:
https://blog.daemonl.com/2016/02/yaml.html

Comment: @jvoigt I need to have references to endpoints in description fields (text) so this does not help me, but thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Swagger UI provides [permalinks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45147928/113116) for tags and operations if it's configured with the `deepLinking: true` option. These permalinks are generated based on the tag names and `operationId` (or if there are no `operationId` - based on the endpoint names and HTTP verbs).

```
index.html#/tagName
index.html#/tagName/operationId
```

You can use these permalinks in your Markdown markup:

```yaml
      description: >
        This endpoint does things.
        See [/my/otherEndpoint](#/tagName/myOtherEndpointId) for stuff
```

Notes:

- Markdown links (such as above) currently open in a new browser tab (as with `target="_blank"`) - see [issue #3473](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3473).
- HTML-formatted links `<a href="#/tagName/operationId">foobar</a>` currently [don't work](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3958).
- Swagger Editor does not support such permalinks.

Comment: right, it depends on the tool we use to render the openapi doc. In my case, I'm using [RapiDoc](https://mrin9.github.io/RapiDoc/). For 'send message' tagged API we can specify link as this -> [Send Message](#tag--send-message). [more info](https://mrin9.github.io/RapiDoc/examples/links)