# Springboot - Reference another endpoint in swagger documentation

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I'm fairly new to Springboot, but I currently develop a RESTful api with Java 8 and Springboot. The api is documented with Swagger.

In the description for one of my endpoints, I want to reference another endpoint. Is there anyway this can be done with a clickable link to this endpoint? The image shows the result when its hard coded, but to clickable

[image]

This shows the relevant section in our pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
  <version>${swagger.version}</version>
</dependency>
<!--Swagger UI-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
  <version>${swagger.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The Spring-Boot with the correct Springfox Swagger plugin should detect all endpoints automatically. Would you provide the relevant dependencies of Spring-Boot and Swagger?

Comment: @Nikolas Being a dotnet-developer I have bit of a trouble to understand what you mean, sorry for that. Is this defined in the pom.xml? We're using Maven.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52703804/how-to-link-to-another-endpoint-in-swagger and https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api

Comment: FYI: We're using swagger version 2.9.2

Comment: @TobiasMoeThorstensen: Yes, Maven is a build automation tool - that's why I ask for your dependencies in pom.xml. One of the many advantages is the way it deals with the dependencies from the central repository. Including Spring-Boot and its relevant dependencies assures autoconfiguration with either minimal or manual configuration using files. Now as I said, including the Springfox Swagger dependency says Spring-Boot to detect all the endpoints and publish them to Swagger.

Comment: @Nikolas Please see my edit. Is this what you need?

Comment: @TobiasMoeThorstensen: Yes, it is :)

Comment: by using `swagger.yml` or bean definition? (maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/52705899/3224238)