# Is it possible to create an HTML link to a specific API within a JSON Swagger file?

Tags: html, json, hyperlink, gitlab, swagger

I have swagger files with URLs like https://gitlab.com//blah/blah/Orders_Swagger.json.  I'm building some documentation that links to these files; that works fine.  Gitlab renders the page with nice formatting.  But some swagger files have dozens of APIs and sometimes I want to reference a specific, critical API, not just send the user to the top of the page.

Comment: I believe GitLab uses Swagger UI as a renderer. Does this answer your question -- [How to link to another endpoint in Swagger UI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52705899/113116)?

Comment: I believe the HTML elements for each API have an ID you can anchor to in the URL fragment. For example, this [link](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/doc/api/openapi/openapi.yaml#operations-access_tokens-accessTokens_get) will take you directly to the endpoint at the bottom of the page (GET access token): `https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/doc/api/openapi/openapi.yaml#operations-access_tokens-accessTokens_get` the URL fragment `#operations-access_tokens-accessTokens_get` anchors you to the specific endpoint when the page is loaded. Would that work for you?

Comment: That's the kind of thing I'm looking for, yes.  However, the link you posted just takes me to the top of the page, which I can already do.

Answer (score 2):

Swagger UI supports a "deepLinking=true" configuration parameter.  It is set to false by support.  Gitlab embeds Swagger UI, but does not provide a way to set this parameter, so it is off at the server level.

However, you can enable it by passing a parameter in the URL:  &deepLinking=1

Thus, a full, API-specific URL will look like this:
https://gitlab.com/company/blah/blah/Swagger.json?deepLinking=1#/section/targetApiName