# Dynamically construct url in swagger for each operation

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-editor, api-doc

I Check the swagger and we can have URL dynamically for various site based on Server specified. But i have doubt whether is it possible to construct URL dynamically for each operation similar like this

http://{serverurl}/{tagName}/{operation}

I know that server url can be configured at the top of swagger.json but how can we configure/add tag name to the URL dynamically.

Example:

consider i have following scenario

I have following tags,

- customer
- user
- admin

  Each tags have various operations associated with them, I need to add the tag name along with operation name dynamically in swagger URL as following

If the operation is getRecentActivity it need to be like

http://www.example.com/{tagname}/{operation}

which is similar like

http://www.example.com/customer/getRecentActivity

Note:- My configuration is in such a way, i know i can directly specify it in path itself by i required it to generate dynamically based on tag name

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please explain it a little more with an example?

Comment: Do you mean [deep links / permalinks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45147928/1131160) for individual tags and operations? If not, please clarify the question.